# Your job matches are on hold

Tags: support, developer-story

I completed everything but the last one—Work experience. I didn't work as a programmer before so I don't have anything to add there.

[image]

Comment: Work experience is not necessary. It says *or* education. That criteria is not met because you haven't written 150 characters about the education.

Comment: Do I need to write 150 chars for each education I add?

Comment: I believe just one of them needs to meet both of the subcriteria (150 character description and two technologies).

Comment: I don't have any ideas about what to write on my degree that other people don't really know already. Is it possible to find examples of other people's profiles?

Comment: Some ideas: any specific courses you took in the degree relevant to the kind of job you're pursuing; any specific focus the degree program had; any relevant projects you did during the program