# Job matches are on hold - although everything is completed

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, developer-story

Note: this question may seem similar to [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337779/your-job-matches-are-on-hold) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320591/job-matches-on-hold-because-why)

On my developer story I am seeing this:

[image]

On the two other questions I've linked to, this error message is showing because the user hasn't completed a section of their developer story, although I have completed every section (as shown by the green ticks in the image).

I haven't made any changes to my developer story in the past few weeks

Why am I seeing this message that my job matches are on hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I introduced this issue yesterday (my code didn't take into consideration that having an education item also qualified for enabling job matches). Sorry and thanks for reporting it! it should be fixed now

Comment: In case it's helpful, I'm still seeing this issue

Comment: @bcattle it is helpful, and it should be fixed now... thanks!

Comment: @g3rv4 I’m having the same problem https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398329.