# Stack Overflow Jobs profile completed, but matches still on hold

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I know this is an exact duplicate of [Job matches are on hold - although everything is completed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339335) but I tried to contact support at https://stackoverflow.com/contact with the right topic days ago and I didn’t receive an answer.

So why am I seeing this message that my job matches are on hold?

Answer (score 1):

The education item on your Dev Story needs at least 2 technology tags and a 75+ character description to be considered "complete".

Comment: For the description, I don t have work experience so I can t add such thing.

Comment: @user2284570 You can add a description detailing the study program, projects you've worked on, etc.

Comment: Not even that. Doing such thing involves finding a company, which is the first reason I m creating the profile.

Comment: @user2284570 I'm referring to the description and tags under your education entry.